# Post to User Wall using offline_access in facebook Javascript Sdk

Tags: facebook

My problem is that i want to post to user wall using the offline_access.

I donot know how to do that using the facebook javascript sdk

with this method FB.api('/me/feed')

Please also give me an example how to integrate the facebook connect with asp

Comment: are you looking to publish from JS when the user is not actively on your site? Please give more details...

Answer (score 0):

If the user has already authenticated and has given publish_stream or offline_access permissions, you can just call this method to publish to their feed:

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```